# How to show image instead of bullets in react native html text?

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-htmlview` to render html text this package gives a lot of customization options what I want to ask is how can I replace bullets with an image or may be a `react-native-vector-icon` component the library gives an option to replace bullet with a text string can I replace it with icon or image? 
Any help would appreciated you may suggest some other light weight package that serve this purpose I also need please keep in mind that I want to apply styles based on the tags and my styles includes the custom font.

Comment: I've never use it but I believe you can use react-native-render-html for your purpose. It seems like the package allows customization.

Comment: I have used react-native-render-html didn't work for me, it throws error whenever I try to use tagsstyle props